# Code in SQL Database and Static Library - iPhone

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, sdk, static-libraries

My app uses a local SQLite database to read data. Just a couple of questions :

- Is this type of database classed as a "Static Database" ?
- Does the database have any code appended to it (e.g Obj C code) when compiled in xCode ?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of SQLite as a library that gets statically compiled and linked with your program and allows you to read and write to a file as if it is a database.

From the SQLite site:

> SQLite is a software library that
>   implements a self-contained,
>   serverless, zero-configuration,
>   transactional SQL database engine.

The data itself can be stored in files on the filesystem and no objective-c code is appended to it. The database does not have to be static, i.e. you can use your code to read or write, from and to the database.  If that is what you meant by static.

Comment: Thanks Yasser. I am trying to track down some illegal api code and wondered of it is in the database - probably not.